# Getting error: *****.apk not found

Tags: android, apk, android-actionbar

I have made one project as a library, while calling that library project to the main project.

I have made an action-bar class and made it a library, while calling it in main project.

I am getting error on Console as **Could not find *Actionbar.apk!**

While logcat shows as follows:

```
01-30 13:36:47.595: E/AndroidRuntime(404): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-30 13:36:47.595: E/AndroidRuntime(404): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sos.emergency/com.sos.emergency.SOSHome}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-30 13:36:47.595: E/AndroidRuntime(404):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
01-30 13:36:47.595: E/AndroidRuntime(404):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
01-30 13:36:47.595: E/AndroidRuntime(404):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
01-30 13:36:47.595: E/AndroidRuntime(404):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
01-30 13:36:47.595: E/AndroidRuntime(404):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-30 13:36:47.595: E/AndroidRuntime(404):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-30 13:36:47.595: E/AndroidRuntime(404):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
01-30 13:36:47.595: E/AndroidRuntime(404):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-30 13:36:47.595: E/AndroidRuntime(404):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-30 13:36:47.595: E/AndroidRuntime(404):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
01-30 13:36:47.595: E/AndroidRuntime(404):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
01-30 13:36:47.595: E/AndroidRuntime(404):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-30 13:36:47.595: E/AndroidRuntime(404): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-30 13:36:47.595: E/AndroidRuntime(404):  at com.sos.emergency.SOSHome.onCreate(SOSHome.java:35)
01-30 13:36:47.595: E/AndroidRuntime(404):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-30 13:36:47.595: E/AndroidRuntime(404):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
01-30 13:36:47.595: E/AndroidRuntime(404):  ... 11 more
```

i am working according to the given link

http://thiranjith.wordpress.com/2011/07/15/actionbar-design-pattern-example-for-android/

along with other reference as,

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html

and

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

I have cleaned my project several times, also tried various solution found on net, but could not solve it.

My code snippet where i am getting error,

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
setContentView(R.layout.home_screen);

ActionBar = (***_Actionbar) findViewById(R.id.actionBar);
ActionBar.setTitle(R.string.app_name); //getting error here
ActionBar.setHomeLogo(R.drawable.ic_title_home_default);
```

Comment: Please add the snippet of your code where you are starting the Activity. It seems as if there is no entry for your activity in the Manifest file.

Comment: just try to clean your project & see apk is generated or not in bin folder again.

Comment: @ Sumant: i did that and still its not working.

Comment: @ Shashank Kadne : Yea i did made a mistake in my manifest file...but now i have made changes to it, but m still getting the null pointer exception(the one i have posted above) and yes  my error on apk not found is gone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to Project-->Properties

Select Android from left-hand side list

Uncheck the "Is Library" checkbox.